# Creating a VPN server using the Debian VPS

Tags: networking, windows-8, debian, vpn, pptp

I have a Debian VPS and I know about PPTP. I have followed the installation process as what is stated here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/199286/create-vpn-server-using-the-ubuntu-vps

However, when I tried to connect to this VPN with my Windows computer through Network and Sharing Center (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center), I get an error message: Error 619: A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for the connection was closed.

I have followed instructions here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoizPT__9dQ on how to connect using a Windows 8 computer (I am using Windows 8 now).

My credentials used are correct.

Comment: why not using openvpn? i won't say it is the best, that'd be subjective but i can tell you that all the major vpn providers use it

Answer (score 1):

- Verify that you can ping or otherwise reach your VPS's public IP, and that current Internet connection isn't blocking the outgoing PPTP port.  If you are using a cellular 3G connection this may be likely.
- Check if `pptpd` is running.  Check `ps aux` for a `ptppd` process.  If you don't see any, look in `/var/log/daemon.log` for a reason why it may have failed to start.  Try a `/etc/init.d/ptppd start` or `service start ptppd`.
- Your `iptables` configuration also has to allow incoming connections on the PPTP port 1723.
  You may need to add a `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT` to your `rc.local` as well.
- If the IP ranges here `localip 192.168.0.1 
  remoteip 192.168.0.2-254` are the same ones as your network (which may happen if you are behind a typical consumer router NAT), this could cause issues.  You should select a different subnet such as 192.168.200.1/192.168.200.2-254.